# Orchard Contrib.DateTimeField missing style and script

Tags: jquery-ui, orchardcms, datetimepicker

`I've installed the DateTime Field module to Orchard and assigned two fields to my custom part, but when navigating to the Admin Edit page for the custom type implimenting the custom part, I recieve an error like this:

```
A 'stylesheet' named 'jQueryUtils_TimePicker' could not be found.
```

When looking in the Contrib.DateTime.cshtml View, I find that the following two resources are required, but I can't find them in the jQuery module's resource manifest.

1. **Style**: `jQueryUtils_TimePicker`
2. **Script**: `jQueryUtils_TimePicker`

Where are these meant to be defined and stored?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.
If I change both to `jQueryUI_TimePicker` (for which there is a script and style defined in the jquery module resource manifest), then it doesn't throws an error, but the time picker doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrib.DateTimeField is obsolete since 1.4 so you shouldn't use it.

The DateTimeField has been integrated in Orchard.Fields has a core feature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where do you find info on this? I can't find any documentation about it.

Comment: This really should be documented somewhere as i still can download `Contrib.DateTimeField` from the gallery and i was fooled also until now.